# Special hollow matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have a hollow matrix $(1395 \times 1395)$ with zero diagonal and the other entries be one on the field,  then to make the matrix invertible how many should be The number of field members ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know what the eigenvalues of this matrix are?  If you added $1$s on the diagonal, do you know what the eigenvalues of the new matrix are?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do this. I can't find eigenvalues

Comment: Not even by (forgive me) by thinking?

Comment: If I knew I would not ask

Comment: If you don't say what you've tried and what you know about this problem, its hard to help.

Comment: @kimchi lover    I can solve it....is this right?

Answer (score 1):

every matrix n*n with zero diagonal and other entries one is invertible and det(A)=(n-1)(-1)^(n+1)

This is the proof of this note:
Let A
  n×n
 matrix, with n≥2
. Then A+I
 is the matrix consisting entirely of 1
s, which clearly has n−1
 zero rows after row-reduction. Therefore A
 has eigenvalue −1
, repeated (at least) n−1
 times, and since trace(A)=0
, the other eigenvalue is n−1
.

Since every eigenvalue of A
 is non-zero, the determinant of A
 is non-zero, so A
 is invertible.

---

So det(A)=1394 and A on every field like F that is |F|  not dividing 1394 is invertible, for example: if  |F|=9.

Comment: Very good, except for the last step: There are fields of characteristic $p$ which have more than $p$ elements.  (Such as $p^k$ elements, or infinitely many elements.) What you say is correct if you exclude fields of characteristic that divides $1394$.

Comment: I mean if 1394 not equivalent to zero in field then the matrix is invertible.